# Please re-open "Automating Presentation of Markdown Pandoc Tables" -- I know a short, working answer!

Tags: discussion, vote-to-reopen

I would like to see the following question re-opened, which I just came across:

- **[Automating extraction of Markdown-formatted tables from an (incomplete) LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245572/8747)**

This has been closed for the reason: *"too broad [...] too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format"*.

After having seen the same user posting in the Pandoc discussion forum in Google Groups, I now know how to answer his question perfectly well, and the gist of it will be very short: I'll use a pipeline of Pandoc and `grep` commands to achieve the desired output. The answer fits into a single Tweet, I promise!

*(I've also tried to improve the wording of the question text and headline -- but it needs to go through review first...)*

Comment: Kurt, instead of creating a question in Meta, you might just flag the question you want re-opened.  It worked for me in this question last week: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77943/how-do-i-create-a-named-subdiagram/246114#246114)

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific.  I flagged it with (3) "in need of moderator intervention".  When I created the flag, it asked for a comment where I asked for a re-open of the question.  I couldn't see the flag That I created, but a moderator did see it and re-opened the question.  Maybe a moderator can comment whether I did it the preferred way or if a question in Meta is better.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @James. Now I "got" it :)

Answer (score 3):

Your request is granted: the question is open :-)

Comment: Had to write a few words to make this count as an answer!

Comment: Thank you, Joseph! :)  -- I managed to put the gist of the answer into less than 140 characters indeed. But explaining its mechanism in finer details took admittedly much more space :)